# Rollup Build failure for SCSS exports to be used in TS ( [!] Error: 'default' is not exported by src/styles/variables.scss )

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sass, rollup, rollupjs

I'm running into the following rollup build failure where I would like to be able to used exports from a scss file in my typescript files.

The build failure reads as follows:

> [!] Error: 'default' is not exported by src/styles/variables.scss,
>   imported by src/components/Layout/Layout.themes.tsx
>   https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#error-name-is-not-exported-by-module
>   src/components/Layout/Layout.themes.tsx (1:7) 1: import vbl from
>   '../../styles/variables.scss';

My rollup config looks as follows:

```
import scss from 'rollup-plugin-scss';
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2';
import image from '@rollup/plugin-image';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';
import pkg from './package.json';

export default {
  input: ['src/index.tsx'],
  output: [
    {
      file: pkg.main,
      format: 'cjs',
      sourcemap: true,
      name: 'Main'
    },
    {
      file: pkg.module,
      format: 'esm',
      sourcemap: true,
      name: 'tree-shaking'
    }
  ],
  external: [...Object.keys(pkg.dependencies || {}), ...Object.keys(pkg.devDependencies || {}), ...Object.keys(pkg.peerDependencies || {})],
  plugins: [image(), scss({ output: 'dist/styles.css' }), typescript({ useTsconfigDeclarationDir: true }), terser()]
};
```

The variables.scss contains:

```
// colors
$color-blue: #1c4077;
$color-orange: #e87d1e;

:export {
  colorBlue: $color-blue;
  colorOrange: $color-orange;
}
```

The variables.scss.d.ts typings file contains:

```
export interface IGlobalScss {
  colorBlue: string;
  colorOrange: string;
}

export const variables: IGlobalScss;

export default variables;
```

And the Layout.themes.tsx file reads as follows:

```
import vbl from '../../styles/variables.scss';

export const myTheme = {
  headerColor: vbl.colorBlue,
  footerColor: vbl.colorOrange
}
```

I've tried an import of the non-default export `import { variables } from '../../styles/variables.scss';` but it fails as well with:

> [!] Error: 'variables' is not exported by src/styles/variables.scss,
>   imported by src/components/Layout/Layout.themes.tsx
>   https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#error-name-is-not-exported-by-module
>   src/components/Layout/Layout.themes.tsx (1:9) 1: import {
>   variables } from '../../styles/variables.scss';

I am able to serve the project via Storybook, however when I build via Rollup I encounter the error listed above. Please assist me in resolving this build failure?

Here is a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rollup-build-failure-scss-773wf) for this example. Extract the zip, **yarn** and run either **yarn start** or **yarn build** to test in VSCode. You'll notice that yarn start succeeds whereas yarn build will fail as mentioned above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem is that the `output` property **is** **not false**.

Here is what the plugin does when that property is set to false:

```js
if (options.output === false) {
  const css = compileToCSS(code)
  return {
    code: 'export default ' + JSON.stringify(css),
    map: { mappings: '' }
  }
}
```

and this happens in the [`transform hook`](https://github.com/thgh/rollup-plugin-scss/blob/master/index.es.js#L70-L76), which is invoked before the parsing takes place. This is important because `export default ...` is treated as a module, meaning you can import it in your js files.

So I think you'll have to manually bundle that `variables` file with:

```js
scss({ output: false }).
```

Now, another problem arises: when you import from the `.scss` file, you'll get the `:export` object stringified.

For example:

```js
"export default ":export {\n  colorBlue: #1c4077;\n  colorOrange: #e87d1e; }\n""
```

the plugin in use [does not seem to handle this](https://github.com/thgh/rollup-plugin-scss/blob/master/index.es.js) case.

So I think the solution involves manipulating that string so that you'd end up with something like this:

```js
`{ colorX: 'value', colorY: 'value' }`
```

Comment: Hmm.. interesting.. I seem to be encountering issues now with @imports ( @ import '../../styles/variables'; - File to import not found or unreadable: ../../styles/variables. ). Is there another suitable plugin that would compile my SCSS in this way without changing the bundled output of 'styles.css' in the dist folder? Or perhaps a cleaner way to share style variables and be able to access them in TSX?

Comment: You’re getting that error because with output:false you’re not including the variables file in the bundle. I’m not aware of any solution, but I’ll look into it tomorrow

Comment: Thanks! I've added a a CodeSandbox for this example linked above for debugging.

Comment: Setting 'scss({ output: false })' seems to not be an option as this causes no styles.css to output which means my styles would be in-accesible in the application that uses the pkg.

Comment: Thanks! For your help Andrei, I was able to resolve this issue by using the rollup-plugin-sass instead.

Comment: That's great! Didn't came to mind to check that out as well. Good luck!

Comment: @Delrog did u find a way to make it work? I'm encountering the same issue with rollup + scss export

Comment: Hi @Delrog, could you solve this? can you upload the solution using rollup-plugin-sass?

Comment: @Delrog would love to see how you got it working with `rollup-plugin-sass` as this is the error I see using that plugin